# Is it possible to access Spine JS models from the browser console?

Tags: spine.js

Is it possible to access Spine JS models from the browser console? and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is: http://jsfiddle.net/SpoBo/rn9zA/

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your app isn't bound to the window, you can always `require` the models you're looking for. Spine's `require` method is bound to the window.

If you have a User model (app/models/user), then you should be able to `User = require 'models/user'`. Then you can User.first() or whatever